# About adding CSS into magento 2

Tags: magento, magento2.2

so i am in a rush to finish a project.

I have magento 2.2 installed with a theme template, so far easy. But i need to apply some changes based on a cliete request. Easy stuff like some colors and spaces the theme provide the fields but my problem is the following:

- How should i had new fonts? like what is the proper way to do it? the way i did it for now does not seams correct since i drop it into \pub\media{theme}\ .. i hacked some other css there to get the fonts, but i dunno if this is the correct approach
- i need to had a funcionality to get all the categories in a html select, but i got really confuse when i need to call blocks and templates then my page just go empty, looks like i am not rooting things correctly, if someone can point me on how to do something like this correctly that would be awesome.
- i am adding a ton of changes into the css, can someone tell me how should i do it about changing the css? do i need to update my theme everytime i change a bit of my css?

Answer (score 0):

When you add CSS in  Magento 2 you need to disable your cache or be practice to run following command

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy --theme Magento/backend  --theme yourthemename/default
```

Note: and please not write any CSS in static folder

Answer (score 0):

1. If you want to add some new fonts in your child theme. Then follow the step in given link http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/using-fonts.html.
2. You can insert the widget (Catalog Category link)[image]
3. When you add CSS in Magento 2 you need to disable your cache or be practice to run following command

   ```
   php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy --theme Magento/backend  --theme yourthemename/default
   ```